R: Simulating Buses Breaking Down
I am working with the R programming language.

Suppose there are 100 buses (bus_1, bus_2,... bus_100).
The bus company sends the first 5 buses (bus_1, bus_2... bus_5) on the first day.
On the first day, each bus has a 0.5 probability of breaking down (once a bus breaks down, it is out of service permanently).
If the bus does not break down on the first day, its sent out on the second day but now it has a probability of breaking down of 0.49. That is each day a bus doesn't break down, the probability of breaking down reduces by 0.01.
When a bus breaks down, it is replaced with the next bus (e..g if bus1, bus2, bus3,bus4, bus5 are there bus2 and bus4 break on the same day, the next day we will have bus1, bus6, bus3, bus7 , bus5).
At any given day, there will always be 5 buses  on the road ... only towards the end when we reach the last 5 buses, they will dwindle down to 4 buses, 3 buses ... until they all break down.

My Question: I am trying to write a simulation which simulates this situation until all buses break down? The final result should be a data frame with 11 columns: day_number (1,2,3...n), x1, x2, x3, x4, x5 (these represent the bus number in that position), p1,p2,p3,p4,p5 (these represent the probabilities of each bus breaking down on that day's row).
Here is what I tried so far using basic loops:
   bus_count <- 100
bus_prob <- rep(0.5, bus_count)
bus_active <- 1:5
results <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 11, nrow = 0))
colnames(results) <- c("day_number", "x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", "p1", "p2", "p3", "p4", "p5")

day_number <- 0
while(length(bus_active) > 0) {
    day_number <- day_number + 1
    breakdown <- runif(length(bus_active)) < bus_prob[bus_active]
    bus_prob[bus_active] <- pmax(bus_prob[bus_active] - 0.01, 0)
    next_bus <- (max(bus_active)+1):(max(bus_active)+sum(breakdown))
    next_bus <- next_bus[next_bus <= bus_count]
    bus_prob[next_bus] <- 0.5
    bus_active <- c(bus_active[!breakdown], next_bus)
    results <- rbind(results, c(day_number, bus_active, bus_prob[bus_active]))
}

# rename bus values to actual names
results[,2:6] <- apply(results[,2:6], 2, function(x) paste0("bus_", x))

print(results)

This is not correct. I am noticing the following errors (column names did not come out correct):
Problem 1: The bus ordering is incorrect. On the first day, the buses should be bus1, bus2, bus3, bus4, bus5.
   X1      X3       X5       X6       X7       X8  X0.49 X0.49.1   X0.5 X0.5.1 X0.5.2
1   1   bus_3    bus_5    bus_6    bus_7    bus_8   0.49    0.49   0.50   0.50    0.5
2   2   bus_3    bus_6    bus_9   bus_10   bus_11   0.48    0.49   0.50   0.50    0.5

Problem 2: Buses are "coming back from the dead". E.g. Day 15 vs Day 47, bus47 comes back
15 15  bus_38   bus_45   bus_46   bus_47   bus_48   0.46    0.49   0.50   0.50    0.5
47 47  bus_47   bus_47   bus_47   bus_47   bus_47  47.00   47.00  47.00  47.00   47.0

Problem 3: The same bus appears multiple times in the same row:
47 47  bus_47   bus_47   bus_47   bus_47   bus_47  47.00   47.00  47.00  47.00   47.0

Problem 4: The probabilities are not in the correct ranges (e.g. can only be between 0.5 and 0)
37 37  bus_98   bus_99   bus_98  bus_0.5  bus_0.5   0.50   37.00  98.00  99.00   98.0
38 38  bus_99   bus_98  bus_100 bus_0.49 bus_0.49   0.50   38.00  99.00  98.00  100.0

Can someone please help me fix these problems and write this code correctly?
Thanks!

Your buses get more reliable as they go - if this is intended, you have the possiblity of a bus hitting 100% chance to continue working.  This means "...simulates this situation until all buses break down?" may be an infinite list.

I think this does what you want. The NBUS variable at the top specifies the number of buses. I've set this to 10 to make the simulation results easier to follow. The results are in long format, which is easier to use for simulation purposes. You can transform into wide format if necessary.
library(dplyr)

NBUS <- 10

buses <- data.frame(
  id = seq(NBUS),
  active = FALSE,
  broken = FALSE,
  pbreakdown = 0.5
)

buses$active[1:5] <- TRUE

day <- 0
#
while (TRUE) {
  day <- day + 1
  cat(paste("* DAY", day, "===\n\n"))
  
  # Sample which buses break down.
  #
  active <- buses %>%
    filter(active) %>%
    mutate(
      random = runif(nrow(.)),
      broken = random < pbreakdown,
      pbreakdown = pbreakdown - ifelse(broken, 0, 0.01)
    ) 
  
  print(active)
  
  buses <- rbind(
    active %>% select(-random),
    buses %>% filter(!active)
  )
  
  # Set broken buses as inactive.
  #
  buses <- buses %>%
    mutate(
      active = active &! broken
    ) %>%
    arrange(broken)
  
  # Activate more buses.
  #
  buses <- buses %>%
    mutate(
      active = row_number() <= 5 & !broken
    )
  
  nactive <- sum(buses$active)
  
  cat(paste("Number of active buses:", nactive, "\n"))
  
  if (nactive == 0) break
}

This is what a run looks like:
* DAY 1 ===
  id active broken pbreakdown     random
1  1   TRUE  FALSE       0.49 0.57234793
2  2   TRUE   TRUE       0.50 0.34210654
3  3   TRUE   TRUE       0.50 0.07598386
4  4   TRUE  FALSE       0.49 0.63736968
5  5   TRUE  FALSE       0.49 0.96737081
Number of active buses: 5 
* DAY 2 ===
  id active broken pbreakdown     random
1  1   TRUE   TRUE       0.49 0.34594576
2  4   TRUE   TRUE       0.49 0.28472555
3  5   TRUE   TRUE       0.49 0.06129289
4  6   TRUE  FALSE       0.49 0.55372494
5  7   TRUE   TRUE       0.50 0.37260161
Number of active buses: 4 
* DAY 3 ===
  id active broken pbreakdown     random
1  6   TRUE   TRUE       0.49 0.12935732
2  8   TRUE  FALSE       0.49 0.53252384
3  9   TRUE   TRUE       0.50 0.04712646
4 10   TRUE  FALSE       0.49 0.59582349
Number of active buses: 2 
* DAY 4 ===
  id active broken pbreakdown    random
1  8   TRUE   TRUE       0.49 0.3852345
2 10   TRUE  FALSE       0.48 0.8734542
Number of active buses: 1 
* DAY 5 ===
  id active broken pbreakdown    random
1 10   TRUE   TRUE       0.48 0.4356555
Number of active buses: 0

The Number of active buses logs reflect the number of active buses after that day's breakdowns have been taken into account.
Here's what happens in the output above:

Day 1 buses 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 are running. Buses 2 and 3 break down.
Day 2 buses 1, 4, 5, 6 and 7 are running. Buses 1, 4, 5 and 7 break down.
Day 3 buses 6, 8, 9 and 10 are running (we now only have four buses left). Buses 6 and 9 break down.
Day 4 buses 8 and 10 are running. Bus 8 breaks down.
Day 5 only bus 10 is running and it also breaks down.

For each day you see a table of the 5 (or fewer) active buses, their breakdown probability and a random number that's used to determine whether or not they break down on that day.
The content of buses data frame at the end looks like this:
   id active broken pbreakdown
1  10  FALSE   TRUE       0.48
2   8  FALSE   TRUE       0.49
3   6  FALSE   TRUE       0.49
4   9  FALSE   TRUE       0.50
5   1  FALSE   TRUE       0.49
6   4  FALSE   TRUE       0.49
7   5  FALSE   TRUE       0.49
8   7  FALSE   TRUE       0.50
9   2  FALSE   TRUE       0.50
10  3  FALSE   TRUE       0.50

They are all broken and none are active. You can calculate how many days each bus was active before it broken down by looking at how much pbreakdown differs from 0.5.

thank you so much for your answer! I think I made a mistake in describing my problem ... each day, there are always 5 buses until we reach the last 5 buses and then they dwindle down 4,3,2,1.

Understood and that is what I have implemented. Look at the sample output where you'll see that there are 5 buses running on days 1 and 2 but that by day 6 all of the buses have broken down.

I have added a text description of the results in my sample run to my answer. That should clarify what is happening.

This is not a complete answer but will make some improvements and hopefully get you moving forward.
"Growing objects in a loop", where your results data frame gets 1 row bigger each loop iteration is a classic performance-killer in R, because when the object outgrows the place in memory where it is stored  it may need to be copied to an entirely new place in memory. It's much better to "pre-allocate", make your object as big or bigger than it needs to be and fill in the holes as you go.
I would re-write you code like this to pre-allocate, and also deal with the column name issues. I also put a set.seed() at the top so that the randomness is reproducible.
set.seed(47)
bus_count <- 100
bus_prob <- rep(0.5, bus_count)
bus_active <- 1:5
n_init = 500
results <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 11, nrow = n_init))
colnames(results) <- c("day_number", "x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", "p1", "p2", "p3", "p4", "p5")
results$day_number = 1:n_init

day_number <- 0
while(length(bus_active) > 0) {
    day_number <- day_number + 1
    breakdown <- runif(length(bus_active)) < bus_prob[bus_active]
    bus_prob[bus_active] <- pmax(bus_prob[bus_active] - 0.01, 0)
    next_bus <- (max(bus_active)+1):(max(bus_active)+sum(breakdown))
    next_bus <- next_bus[next_bus <= bus_count]
    bus_prob[next_bus] <- 0.5
    bus_active <- c(bus_active[!breakdown], next_bus)
    results[day_number, -1] <- c(as.list(bus_active), as.list(bus_prob[bus_active]))
}

After stepping 3 times through the loop, this is how the results are looking:
head(results)
#   day_number x1 x2 x3 x4 x5   p1   p2   p3   p4  p5
# 1          1  1  3  4  5  6 0.49 0.49 0.49 0.49 0.5
# 2          2  1  5  6  7  8 0.48 0.48 0.49 0.50 0.5
# 3          3  5  7  8  9 10 0.47 0.49 0.49 0.50 0.5
# 4          4 NA NA NA NA NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  NA
# 5          5 NA NA NA NA NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  NA
# 6          6 NA NA NA NA NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  NA

Based on this, I would say your next issues to tackle are

I would assume you want the x1 to x5 be the buses that are out on day_number. But as you can see you start with bus_active <- 1:5 and they never make it into the data frame because you calculate the breakdowns and get the new buses before you do any inserting. Also notice that the p1:p5 on row 1 are the values you want on row 2.

You correctly point out a length issue at the end. Use if statements to deal with it, e.g., if(length(bus_active) < 5) {bus_active <- c(bus_active, rep(NA, 5 - length_bus_active))}. You will need to make sure the NAs don't mess up the rest of your code.

(Maybe change your condition to while(any(!is.na(bus_active))) so the loop runs as non-NA values are in bus_active.



Some other advice:
Start small! Instead of 100 total, with 5 out at a time, write you code for 10 buses out 3 at a time. When that works, scale it up. Similarly, the probabilities change so slowly as to be unnoticeable.  If there was a bug in them, you might never notice. Maybe make the breakdown probability start at 60% but go down by 10% each day.
(You might also want to make the floor of the breakdown probability greater than 0, especially in this case, so you don't get an infinite loop. Maybe have it bottom out at 10%.)
